# Error installing arch Linux due to virtual box-guest-modules (despite not installing on virtual machine)

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation, virtualbox, pacman

I'm installing Arch Linux, following the instructions at the [Beginners' Guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_guide), and got up to running `pacstrap -i /mnt base base-devel`.

It finishes with the following error:

```
resolving dependencies...
looking for inter-conflicts...
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: virtualbox-guest-modules: requires linux<3.15
==> ERROR: Failed to install packages to new root
```

What is really weird is that I'm not installing Arch in a virtual machine, I'm setting it up to dual boot on my laptop.

Comment: does it still happen if you omit `base-devel`? Arch doesn't just install things on its own, you must have pulled it in somehow. are you sure that's the _exact_ command you typed?

Comment: It still happens if I omit base-devel. I am installing over a previous Linux distro if that effects anything?

Comment: it _shouldn't_ affect anything, but there can't be any harm in getting rid of it. is your `/home` on the same partition as the other distribution? if not, personally I would nuke the filesystem, just to be safe. this is very weird.

Comment: Well, strangely enough that worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was installing arch Linux over a previous Linux installation. Once I'd wiped the filesystem it all worked.